# Lotus Notes "Format painter" or Quick access to fonts

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I got Lotus Notes 7.0.3 at my job and I miss the "format painter" to copy the style in my mails. Does it exist?

If not, the biggest problems I got are when I paste text form another program. The style is imported and I don't like that. I got to search for the "Default sans serif" font (witch is somewhere in the middle of the font list, another annoying thing).

Basically, I use "Default sans serif" for text and "Default Monospace" for code. Is there a way to put them at the top of the font list of to get a quick access to them, or maybe in a toolbar or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found there is a Style feature hidden in the ***Text*** menu.
After even deeper searching, i found that you could edit those styles uneder the ***Text-text property*** menu.

So i deleted the default styles and created some that fit my requirement. After some try, i found that the is a ***assign to keyboard*** button where you got to check those style.

So I could now access those styles using the ***F11*** key. There is also a button on the tool bar for that.

Answer (score 3):

Use this keyboard shortcut to apply basic style

Highlight the text to be reformatted, then hold Alt and press (sequentially) t y b  (for text, style, basic)

Comment: Note that the keys are for the English-language menus. In other languages, the keys may be different.